# Highchart is taking too much space from top bottom. Please help me to find out "How do i control the spacing in highchart"?

Tags: highcharts

[image: remove highchart spaces]

This is the script I am using. chart should take space according to his size. But he is taking 400px height. Please let me know if you have any solution for this issue.

```
renderChart() {
    this.view = 'chart'

    setTimeout(() => {
        jQuery('.user-charts').each((index, element) => {

            Highcharts.chart(jQuery(element).attr('id'), {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Stacked bar chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['100% BHV.nl B.V.']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                        }
                },
                legend: {
                    reversed: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5]
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [2]
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [3]
                }]
            });
        })

    }, 1000)
    // chart
    var char_div = document.querySelector('.chart');
},
```

Comment: `chart should take space according to his size.` - Could you explain what you have in mind? By default, Highcharts sets the height as 400 px and adjusts elements to fit this height - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height

Comment: yes you are right.  Chart sets the height 400px automatically. But if i need chart with 200px height then how can i increase or decrease height?

Comment: @Arsian - you can manipulate the chart height by setting the chart.height config - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nfo3kumz/ or by setting the height for the container and chart will adapt height to this height - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p68gczx4/